# Setting iframe src attribute in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, iframe

I am trying to show a preview of the HTML code typed into textarea when a preview button is clicked through iframe.

I have attempted to use the setAttribute function of Renderer2 but keep getting a

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')

Below is the relevant code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
<textarea #postform id="postform" [(ngModel)]="this.display[0].MDFile" class="textarea_MD" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; height: 550px; width:600px; " placeholder="Enter markdown here"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<button class="btn" (click)="saveMD()">Save</button>
<p></p>
<button class="btn" (click)="previewHTML()">Preview HTML</button>
<button class="btn" (click)="toDashboard()">Dashboard</button>
</div>
<iframe srcdoc="" class="preview" title="Preview"></iframe>
```

**Component.ts**

```
  previewHTML(): void {
    let html: any = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.display[0].MDFile);
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.preview.nativeElement, 'src','data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html));
  }
```

`this.display[0].MDFile` is where the HTML content/text is saved by a two-way binding NgModel.

What could be the cause of the TypeError and could there be a way to resolve this?

If not, any advice on achieving the HTML preview would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out didn't even need to use Renderer2.

Changed the code to:

**HTML**

`<iframe [src]='html' class="preview" title="Preview"></iframe>`

**Component.ts**

```
previewHTML(): void {
    let file ='data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(this.display[0].MDFile);
    this.html = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(file);
  }
```